# Pandas faster algorithm for accumulating values in a column based on sorted timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
UserId| links  | timestamp
---------------------------
user1 | link1  | 1624245350
user2 | link23 | 1624255350
user2 | link15 | 1624235250
user1 | link12 | 1624245250
user1 | link20 | 1624245150
user2 | link1  | 1624234150
user3 | link15 | 1624235550
user2 | link34 | 1624235152
user3 | link1  | 1624231234
user1 | link16 | 1614245350
```

I need to transform the above to the following dataFrame below. Note, each user will need to be sorted by timestamp with a new column called linkHistory. linkHistory is an accumulation of links that the user has clicked on in the past before they clicked on the current link shown in the links column. Hence, the first linkHistory for every user should be an empty string.

```
UserId| links  | timestamp   |  linkHistory 
------------------------------------------
user1 | link16 | 1614245350  | ''
user1 | link20 | 1624245150  | link16
user1 | link12 | 1624245250  | link16 link20
user1 | link1  | 1624245350  | link16 link20 link12 
user2 | link1  | 1624234150  | ''
user2 | link15 | 1624235250  | link1
user2 | link23 | 1624255350  | link1 link15
user3 | link1  | 1624231234  | ''
user3 | link15 | 1624235550  | link1
```

The algo below works well for smaller data sets (~10,000), however, once I start to scale up to larger 1M rows, it gets very slow.

```
df = df.sort_values(['UserId', 'timestamp'], ignore_index=True)
# Join Previous links per group
df['linkHistory'] = [
    ' '.join(g.iloc[1:]) for g in
    df.groupby('UserId')['links'].shift(fill_value='')  # Offset Links
        .groupby(df['UserId']).expanding()  # Create Expanding Window to join
]
```

Any ideas for how to do this faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `apply` a custom function using `cumsum`:

```
df["linkHistory"] = df.groupby("UserId")["links"].apply(lambda d: (d+",").shift().fillna("").cumsum().str[:-1])

print (df)

  UserId   links   timestamp           linkHistory
0  user1  link16  1614245350                      
1  user1  link20  1624245150                link16
2  user1  link12  1624245250         link16,link20
3  user1   link1  1624245350  link16,link20,link12
4  user2   link1  1624234150                      
5  user2  link34  1624235152                 link1
6  user2  link15  1624235250          link1,link34
7  user2  link23  1624255350   link1,link34,link15
8  user3   link1  1624231234                      
9  user3  link15  1624235550                 link1
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is so much faster!